# How to write a registry key and value in bundle of wix?

Tags: wix, registry, bootstrapper

I can write a registry key and value in setup project of wix,the code like this:

```
<RegistryKey Id="WinApp" Root="HKLM" Key="Software\App\[ProductName]" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall" >
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="InstallName" Value="[ProductName]" Action="write" KeyPath="yes"></RegistryValue>
    </RegistryKey>
```

How can i do in bootstrapper project?

Answer (score 8):

`Bundles` do not modify the machine state. The registry key should be placed in one of the chained packages to be part of the installation transaction.